# How do I automate Gulp tasks so they run at a pre-defined time?

Tags: gulp

I have Gulp tasks for doing DEV builds that I want to run every hour or so and automatically push my code.  Currently I have to go to the command line every hour and run a task.  I would like to make it so that this happens on its own.  I am on a project team so I don't want to just turn on a watcher and do this every time a file changes.

Does anyone know of a way to set a time increment for a gulp task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of the cron modules to have your task schedule a periodic invocation of the desired tasks. To find your cron module just search in google 'npm cron'. To invoke tasks, try gulp-chug.

Thank you for choosing gulp :-)

Comment: For some reason I didn't think about using node cron.  I was going to just use Windows Scheduler to schedule it but didn't like being tied to Windows.

Comment: So now you are free :-) Btw, there are many various modules, spend time picking the right one for your needs